# Error 0x80244018 installing any Linux distribution under WSL

Tags: installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to use WSL under Windows 10 Pro, and while WSL itself was installed without a problem, I cannot install any Linux distribution under it.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --version
WSL version: 1.0.3.0
Kernel version: 5.15.79.1
WSLg version: 1.0.47
MSRDC version: 1.2.3575
Direct3D version: 1.606.4
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.19042.2486
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl -l
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.

Use 'wsl.exe --list --online' to list available distributions
and 'wsl.exe --install <Distro>' to install.

Distributions can also be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore
Error code: Wsl/WSL_E_DEFAULT_DISTRO_NOT_FOUND
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl -l -o
The following is a list of valid distributions that can be installed.
Install using 'wsl.exe --install <Distro>'.

NAME               FRIENDLY NAME
Ubuntu             Ubuntu
Debian             Debian GNU/Linux
kali-linux         Kali Linux Rolling
SLES-12            SUSE Linux Enterprise Server v12
SLES-15            SUSE Linux Enterprise Server v15
Ubuntu-18.04       Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Ubuntu-20.04       Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Ubuntu-22.04       Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
OracleLinux_8_5    Oracle Linux 8.5
OracleLinux_7_9    Oracle Linux 7.9
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --install Ubuntu
Installing: Ubuntu
Error: 0x80244018           0.0%                           ]
Error code: Wsl/InstallDistro/0x80244018
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --install Debian
Installing: Debian GNU/Linux
Error: 0x80244018           0.0%                           ]
Error code: Wsl/InstallDistro/0x80244018
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

I did try disabling proxy, as I found in one of the posts, but instead of `Error: 0x80244018` got `Catastrophic Failure`.

Can anybody recommend what I can do to install a distro?

Comment: Which version of WSL did you install? The legacy version or the one off the Windows Store which is now the prefered version?

Comment: As a heads-up, your post was migrated here from Stack Overflow because it wasn't about programming.  You can simply log in here on Super User (and any other Stack Exchange site) with your Stack Overflow username and password, and it will create your account here and associate it with your question.  You'll then be able to respond to comments here so that we can help troubleshoot the issue.  Do *not* create a different account, as that user won't be able to respond here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I believe you've discovered (from your proxy comment), this error is usually due to a failure in the Windows Update service.  By default, WSL uses this service to install distributions from the Microsoft Store, but many other Windows components and applications use the service as well.

While the information below may help with WSL, it's likely that you have a more significant issue that you'll need to resolve.  If that's the case, you'll probably want to post a new question that is broader in scope, rather than just this one that focuses on WSL.

That said, my suggested workaround for installing WSL distributions would be to try:

```
wsl --install --web-download Debian
```

The `--web-download` option skips the Store (and shouldn't use the Windows Update service), and will download the distribution directly then install it.

Alternatively, if you can get access to a working Docker installation apart from this system, you could use the steps found in [Import any Linux distribution to use with WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/use-custom-distro).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did work.

Comment: You sir just saved my day.